# Pass arguments from aspx to user control code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to pass some labels of text from db to my user control inside a repeater, but without any success. It doesn't seem to pass my variable.

See discount variable for example

My Default.cs:

```
public String strDiscount { get; set; }
...
strDiscount = getCaptionFromDB("strDiscount");
```

My Default.aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ItemType="MyProduct" ID="ProductsGrid" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:productRow runat="server" Item="<%#Item%>" strDiscount="<%#strDiscount%>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My product user control:

```
public partial class Product : System.Web.UI.UserControl {

    public String strDiscount { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    ... 
    }
```

My ProductRow user control ascx.cs:

```
public partial class ProductRow : Product {

}
```

My ProductRow user control ascx:

```
...
<%:Item.BonusGetValue%>% <%:strDiscount %>
...
```

I must be doing something wrong, but i don't know what.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think strDiscount is in scope. You would need to add ClassName='MyDefaultPage" attribute to your container pages page declaration. This allows you to treat it like a class.

Then in  your control you need to get a reference to this page and its property like this in the control codebehind

```
    var myDefault = (MyDefaultPage) this.Page();
    string discount = myDefault.strDiscount
```